# virtualbox/vagrant で、 /etc/resolv.conf での nameserver が 8.8.8.8 として恒久的に利用するようにしたい

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

vagrant/virtualbox で ubuntu 16.04 を動かしています。 以前投稿した質問の中に、ドメイン名解決ができなくなる場合があり、その場合には /etc/resolv.conf の中で nameserver の指定を 8.8.8.8 にすればひとまず解決する、というものでした。 参照: [PCをスリープさせると、 vagrant からホスト名の解決ができなくなる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36394/754)

これで、問題が発生した場合には /etc/resolv.conf を 8.8.8.8 に書き換えることで対処していたのですが、ふと気づくと、ここの値が、勝手にもともとの値である 10.0.2.3 (デフォルトの nameserver, たまに動かなくなる) に書き換わっていることに気がつきました。

おそらく、 `resolv.conf` の中で、「このファイルはその他もろもろによって自動生成されるよ」と書いてあること、また、デフォルトの nameserver はおそらく VirtualBox が提供している DNS を利用しているのではないか、と考えていて、だとすると VirtualBox (もしくは vagrant の設定)が、これを書き換えているのかな、と思っています。

質問:

- VirtualBox/Vagrant の構成で、「たまに 10.0.2.3 の DNSサーバーが動かなくなる」を、恒久的に対応したいと考えています。 VirtualBox/Vagrant の設定で、利用する DNS を 8.8.8.8 に指定できるのではないか、と考えているのですが、これを行う方法などありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> おそらく、 resolv.conf の中で、「このファイルはその他もろもろによって自動生成されるよ」と書いてあること

が、

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

の事でしたら、「/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail」というファイル(もしなければ作る)に以下のように記述します。

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

---

再起動で反映されると思いますが、上記の設定をすぐに反映させるには、以下のコマンドを実行してください。

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

---

ついでに、DNSの不具合について。

自分はデスクトップPCにlinuxmintを使用していますが、起動直後に名前解決ができないことがありました。(二度目はちゃんと動作する)

どうやらdnsmasqというものが悪さをしているという話を聞いたので、「/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf」の以下の行を以下のようにコメントアウトすると、名前解決ができるようになりました。

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

もちろん、変更したらNetworkManagerの再起動が必要です。

ご参考になるかわかりませんが、一応追記しておきます。
(本当はこちらを最初に回答として書こうと思っていましたが)
なお、dnsmasqは[ubuntu16.10では使われなくなった](https://kledgeb.blogspot.jp/2016/06/ubuntu-1610-7-dnssystemd-resolved.html)そうです。