# ホストOSがスリープから復帰すると、ゲストOSでドメインの名前解決に失敗してネットワークに接続できません

Tags: linux, virtualbox, dns

## 環境

- VirtualBox 7.0.6 r155176 (Qt5.15.2)
- ホストOS: Windows11 Pro 22H2
- ゲストOS: XUbuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- ノートPC: [Dell XPS 15 9570](https://www.dell.com/support/home/ja-jp/product-support/product/xps-15-9570-laptop/docs)

## 起きていること

VirtualBoxで、Xubuntu22.04を利用しています。
ホスト側（Windows11）でスリープ状態から復帰する際、ゲストOS側でネットワークに接続できないときがたまにあります。再現条件は分かりません。
IPアドレスでの接続は可能だったので、名前解決に失敗しているようです。
また、ホストOS（Windows）では問題なくネットワークに接続できます。

## ネットワークに接続できないときに確認したこと

ネットワークに接続できないときに、ゲストOS側で以下のコマンドを実行して確認しました。

#### pingコマンド

```
$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: 名前解決に一時的に失敗しました

# www.google.comのIPアドレスにpingする
$ ping 142.251.42.164
PING 142.251.42.164 (142.251.42.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 142.251.42.164: icmp_seq=1 ttl=112 time=21.1 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.42.164: icmp_seq=2 ttl=112 time=18.5 ms
```

#### 名前解決の設定ファイル

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

#### ネットワーク設定

```
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether xxxxxx  txqueuelen 0  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 xxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (イーサネット)
        RX packets 2014394  bytes 2942152700 (2.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 443618  bytes 33710935 (33.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (ローカルループバック)
        RX packets 207762  bytes 556392050 (556.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 207762  bytes 556392050 (556.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:23:d0:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c1:27:ec:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

#### VirtaulBoxのネットワーク設定

- 割り当て: NAT

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 質問

ゲストOSで名前解決ができていない場合、あと何を確認して、どのように対応すればよいでしょうか？

## 補足

VirtualBoxを再起動すれば、問題なくネットワークに接続できます。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36394/7347 と同じ現象かと思われます。DNSを8.8.8.8等に設定すると正常にアクセスできたりしますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。この現象に近そうですね。
今はネットワーク接続できているので、問題が起きたときに試します。